# How to find all possible combination, selecting n per group without replacement?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, if I have 3 groups

```
g1={1,2,3} g2={3,4,5} g3={7,8}
```

and I select from each group

```
n1=2, n2=1, n3=1
```

All my groups are going to be something like

```
{1,2,3,7}
{1,2,3,8}
...
{1,3,3,7} //you can repeat from different groups
...
{2,3,5,7}
{2,3,5,8}
```

How do I count the number of total groups?

Comment: If the "groups" intersect (as in your example), your question is not clear.  Is $\{1,3,7\}$ a good selection given your example?  Why or why not?

Comment: Are you selecting with or without replacement? Also, does order matter? I.e. are you counting combinations or permutations?

Comment: @k_moreno I could be mistaken, but I assume that the selection must be without replacement.  That is, if the 1st *group* has $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, since the end result is a selection of elements that are used to form a set, then it wouldn't make any sense to select the same element more than once from the same group.

Comment: If it were me, I'd just count the possibilities by hand. It's not going to be that many. This problem has a sufficient number of little wrinkles that a formula will be messy.

Comment: You've been here for 7 years and 10 months. You should be using MathJax by now.

Comment: Exactly, {1,3,7} and not {1,3,3,7} and selecting without replacement, {1,2,3,4,5} should not be possible because you select only 1 element from the second group

Comment: What does that mean?  Is $\{1,3,7\}$ a good selection or not?

Comment: Assume, re the comment of @lulu that there is no intersection between groups (otherwise, the enumeration is much more complicated).  Suppose that you have $r$ groups that are denoted $g_1, g_2, \cdots, g_r$. 
 Further suppose that their respective sizes are $s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_r$.  Further suppose that you will select $k_i$ elements from group $g_i ~: ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots, r\}$, where $k_i \leq s_i$.  Then, the number of ways that the elements can be selected from group $g_i$ is $\displaystyle \binom{s_i}{k_i}.$  ...see next comment.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Why ask your readers to guess at your intent?

Comment: Then, to compute the overall enumeration, you take the product of these $r$ factors.

Comment: Ideally yes, {1,3,7}, but I think the formula will be very messy, is it possible? if not {1,3,3,7} taking the 3 from the first and 3 from the second group

Comment: I don't understand at all.  Is $\{1,3,7\}$ a good selection or not?  The answer should be "Yes it is" or "No it isn't".  There is no notion of "ideally" here, it's just a matter of definitions.

Comment: To state the obvious, if $\{1,3,7\}$ is good then the answer is just the product of binomial coefficients (with the understanding that, if you select the same element more than once, then you simply delete duplicate copies from the final set).  If it's bad, then the answer is very messy.

Comment: Is as user2661923 said, that was what I want at the beginning, but if the two groups intersect I guess it will be very hard to get a formula, so without intersection is fine. So no, it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select {1,2} from the first group, then there are three options for group 2, and two options for group 3, so six total combinations with {1,2}.

If you select {1,3} or {2,3}, there are really only two options from group 2, and still two from group 3. So there are four combinations each.

4+4+6=14.

I'm making lots of assumptions here about what is wanted, but that's my best guess.

Comment: Thank you k_moreno